# how to limit this loop ..just three loops..thanks for helping

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

```
<?php

    @foreach($all_published_products as $product)

            <div>
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                            <img style="height: 150px;" src="{{URL::to($product->product_image)}}" alt="" />
                            <h5>{{$product->product_price}}</h5>
                            <p>{{$product->product_name}}</p>
                            <div style="">
                            @include('items.btn_add_cart_slider')
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    @endforeach

?>
```

Comment: do `$all_published_products = array_chunk($all_published_products,3,true)[0];` before `foreach()`

Answer (score 1):

You can be use `loop` variable  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable

```
@foreach($all_published_products as $product)
    @if($loop->index > 2)
        @breack
    @endif
    .........
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is your query in a model.